# Email From Linux Using Stunnel

Tags: postfix, stunnel, amazon-ses

I'm trying to send an email from a linux instance using stunnel and AWS SES as outlined [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/postfix.html).

I've been through the above documention and and I seem to be getting a connection to my server that has stunnel installed but I'm not receiving any emails. Am I understanding stunnel correctly.

I have it running on my proxy server that is the only server with internet connection in my VPC, I have stunnel configured to route smtp traffic to SES when it receives a request via a specific port. I set up postfix to point to my proxy as the smtp sever with specific port and user credentials for SMTP. Then smtp traffic get routed securely to SES.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"I'm not receiving any emails."*  It sounds like this means you are still not able to **send** emails.  Is that correct?  What's in the postfix logs? The stunnel logs?

Comment: postfix reload seemed to help. Even though I've done a postfix stop and a postfix start and I think even a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

postfix reload seemed to help along with configuring etc/postfix/generic correctly to rewrite the from address correctly when emailing. Even though I've done a postfix stop and a postfix start and I think even a reboot.

This help https://superuser.com/questions/695170/changing-default-from-e-mail-address-for-system-accounts-when-using-sendmail

`root noreply@company.com 
 otheruser noreply@company.com`